# 404 Error on ZF2 skeleton application on all tutorials

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to learn Zend Framework 2. I have followed both the tutorial found in the ZF2 user guide at http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html
and the book Learn ZF2: Learning by example. I've also tried a few other tutorials. I feel like I have wasted so much time and money trying to learn Zend Framework, and can't even get started because I can't even get the welcome screen to load. I have tried so many different things and can not even get the Framework to work. I can get the files to download with Git and Composer (just like in the tutorials). I go to pull up the welcome page and I get the same thing on every tutorial. The header and footer load, but the page is just a 404 error. I wish I could load a picture, but I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't have enough reputation points to do so. You can see an image of what I am getting here: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/file/n4655190/2012-06-01_23-33-29.png;cid=1338564278895-916
I am using the PHP server, included with PHP5, and have made no changes at all to any of the Zend Framework file.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the skeleton app at all? Can you try showing exceptions to see if you get a better error message: create a file at `config/autoload/local.php` that contains this: https://gist.github.com/tfountain/f18505901bd639992cbd and then refresh the error page.

Comment: Also, the screenshot you linked to, did you post that? Or is it just an error similar to what you are getting, as there really should be more info on there.

Comment: I haven't made any changes at all to the skeleton app. I wouldn't know what to change, as I've not learned a single bit about ZF2. Still trying to get it to work so I can start learning it. The image I linked to isn't one I uploaded, but it is the exact page I am getting.

Comment: did you enable mod rewrite? the problem is in your apache config i guess